# Is there any way to position the cursor in a :substitute replace pattern?

Tags: substitute, cursor

I have the following line:

```
return err
```

And would like to replace that to:

```
return fmt.Errorf(": %w", \1)
```

Which is done easily with something like:

```
:s/return \v(\k+)/return fmt.Errorf(": %w", \1)/
```

The problem with this is that after the `:s` my cursor position will be at the start of the line (the `r` in `return`), while it would be much more useful to place it on the `:`.

Is there any way to set the cursor position in the substitute replace pattern?

Comment: I don't think so. Only workaround I can imagine would be to define a custom command that performs the `:s` command, using a sub-replace expression, that calls a function `\=MyReplace` that drops a mark anywhere on the pattern and the command would then after successful substitution move to that mark. Sounds complicated :/

Comment: I [did it like this for now](https://github.com/arp242/zev.vim/commit/b4bfaf5ed0a30d539c68d6d545622fe5a5afec3f#diff-75550fb73a3e377ca6ace681101cb08cR76), but meh

Answer (score 1):

Unfortuately, that's not possible, but hey, vimscript is here to help you:

```
function! Sub(search, replacement, flags)
    norm!^

    let pos = searchpos(a:search, a:flags.'n')

    exe ':s/'.a:search.'/'.a:replacement.'/'.a:flags

    call setpos('.', [0] + pos + [0])

endfunction
```

This function acts exactly like `:s/.../.../...` except it leaves your cursor on the replaced part

It's not perfect, especially if you're used to type `:s/....` to replace, but It gets the job done